# How to generate shareable QR code for expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a Expo RN project. I used to upload my js/ts bundle to expo server and share a shareable QR code. My teams can scan this QR code with Expo Go app from anywhere to view the app. But I can't find anything mentioning this anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't find it mentioned anywhere because it's not supported anymore. The Expo Go app is only meant for providing a development environment now.

The preferred way to share pre-release versions of your app is now by building and sharing APK packages for Android and either using ad-hoc / enterprise distribution or TestFlight for iOS. Expo has a [full page in its documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/sharing-preview-releases/) around this matter.

Once people have the app installed, you can then use [EAS Update](https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/introduction/) to push new preview versions when the JavaScript of your app has been updated (when there have been changes to the native code, you'll need to build and distribute new app bundles though using the methods mentioned above).